# 'L' character pattern in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching, simpledateformat

I can try to use 'L' character in pattern(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("d LLLL y 'г'. H:mm:ss z", new Locale("ru", "RU"));
```

but i get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character - 'L'
```

Any ideas, why it happens?

Comment: Same problem for me with your code. I checked the source code for SimpleDateFormat (http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/libcore.git;a=blob;f=luni/src/main/java/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java;h=e1ff700cb646e4c64106a97fefdb6d8b5610d2f7;hb=HEAD) and 'L' char is well present in the allowed chars list at least since 2010-06-11 according to file history. But I don't know a lot about this part of the source code and I'm not sure where/when it is used or even if it is the appropriate source...

Comment: I have the same problem. With Androi 2.3 its working properly. With 2.1 and less it crashes with LLLL. Does someone has a workaround?

Answer (score 8):

The L character pattern seems not supported on Android versions 2.2 and below. I found the same problem when looking for a solution for date formats in slavic languages (see my comment to XtopherSD's answer). I ended up coding the format conditionally:

```
String fmt = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 8 ? "MMMM yyyy" : "LLLL yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat(fmt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course I was doing development using and API level 16 emulated device, where everything worked fine.  When I tried to run it on an API level 7 emulated devices, I got the same error.

The man page for SimpleDateFormat, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html, says "L" is valid for the month.  It also says "M" is valid.

I changed :

```
private static SimpleDateFormat sdf_myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("LLLL d yyyy HHmm", Locale.US);
```

to :

```
private static SimpleDateFormat sdf_myDate= new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d yyyy HHmm", Locale.US);
```

and it worked on both API 7 and 16.

Comment: Yes, it's true, MMMM and LLLL are equivalent, but not for slavic languages. Polish and Russian users of my calendar app complained that the format MMMM gives is not correct in their languages. From a Polish user's support mail:

"... In English both [MMMM and LLLLL] translate to the same string, e.g. January. In some other languages [like Polish] they translate respectively to 'stycznia' (means 'of January', used e.g. for '13th of January')  and 'styczen' (which means just 'January') and in Polish can't be used with e.g. day of month, but only stand-alone"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but with the 'A' character, after having a look on the SimpleDateFormat API, there is no 'A' pattern letter, just 'a'. And it works properly when I changed to 'a' pattern letter. I don't see your 'L' pattern letter as well,  so it maybe the problem.

[Take a look here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Hope this is helpfull.

Comment: so it maybe a bug of the android 2.2 and previous. I am working on the 2.1